# Blur effect to whole website but one whild element

Tags: html, css

I've added this `.blur` class to `body` tag to blur whole website.

CSS

```css
.blur {
    filter: blur(1px);
    filter: url("blur.svg#gaussian_blur");
    -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
    -o-filter: blur(2px);
}
```

HTML

```
<body class="blur">
...
<div class="mustBeClear"></div> <!-- somewhere in the page-->
...
</body>
```

How to keep `.mustBeClear` class not blured.

I've tried

```css
.mustBeClear{
    filter: none; 
    -webkit-filter: none;
    -o-filter: none;
}
```

but, it does not work!

Comment: Are you using webkit?

Comment: want to have the same effect on all browsers, so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is **not possible**. Because SVG filters get applied to an entire element at once, you **cannot** then selectively "undo" the filter for a single child element.

What I would recommend instead is to only blur the element that you want to be blurred, then you can use absolute positioning on another element on top that does not have the blur effect.

Here is a live example to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}

.blur {
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
}

#text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="blur">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/5LGqY2p.jpg?1" />
    </div>
    <div id="text">Not Blurred Text</div>
</div>
```